# Accessing a GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT texture

Tags: c++, glsl

I am currently trying to implement screen space ambient occlusion. My idea is to do it, as is standard, with multipass rendering, where I use the depth information of the previous pass to calculate the occlusion factor. Therefore, in my "setup" code i created a framebuffer and texture object and bound those together. The texture was created using GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 as internal format and i am issuing a glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE) call since i do not want any color output.

Furthermore I have 3 instances of classes called AnimatedObject which have their own draw methods, and a Renderer Class to wrap all of them when drawing. At the moment my Renderer does something along the lines of

```
drawIntoDepthBuffer(); 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
drawOntoScreen();
```

Where in the above snippet `drawIntoDepthBuffer()` uses my depth buffer program and `drawOntoScreen()` uses the main vertex and fragment shaders. The problem i am now facing is the following: I simply can not access the texture I rendered to in the second draw call. The shaders all compile and link fine. Using the depth buffer program to draw to the screen produces perfectly fine output, also not using the rendered texture in the main shader produces the expected results.

The error I get is the generic OpenGL error

> error: OpenGL error: Invalid operation (1282)

I have also tried using a `sampler2Dshadow` uniform in the main shader, but in that case I really would not know how to access it, since you need a `vec3` to sample it and this simply does not make sense in my case.

Here are the different code pieces:

"Main" fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D texture_main;
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D depth_map;

in vec3 normal;
in vec2 uv;

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    float test = texture(depth_map, gl_FragCoord.xy / textureSize(depth_map, 0)).r; //<---- this fails
    float lambert = clamp(dot(normalize(normal), normalize(vec3(-0.5,1,1))), 0.2f, 1);
    outColor = test * lambert * texture(texture_main, uv);
}
```

Depth fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) out float fragment_depth;

void main() {
    fragment_depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

The vertex shaders for both stages are identical and look like the following:

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 inUv;

uniform mat4 mvp;

out vec3 normal;
out vec2 uv;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = mvp * inPos;
   normal = inverse(transpose(mvp)) * inNormal;
   uv = inUv;
}
```

The corresponding draw calls looks something along those lines:

```
void draw_screen(GLuint depth_texture)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glUseProgram(main_program);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture);

    for (const auto& surface : surfaces)
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0));
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, pos, count);
        pos += pos_increment;
    }
}

void draw_depth(GLuint framebuffer_id)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_id);
    glUseProgram(depth_program);

    for (const auto& surface : surfaces)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, pos, count);
        pos += pos_increment;
    }
}
```

And here is the setup for the framebuffer object:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &depth_framebuffer_id);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depth_framebuffer_id);

glGenTextures(1, &depth_texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture_id);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, viewport_width, viewport_height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depth_texture_id, 0);

glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

Im sorry for so much code, but thats what it needs to tie all this together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: After fiddling around for a few hours i found that the error gets raised by a call to `glUniformMatrix4fv(location_mvp, 1, GL_TRUE, mvp._m)`, which as the name suggests, sets the MVP matrix uniform. When I comment this line out, the depth_map sampler can read from the texture (but it obviously only contains garbage values). On the other hand, if i leae this line in, the code only works whe i do not access the depth_map sampler. What could be the cause of this?

---

Well, it seems like the location of the mvp matrix changes after the first run of the shading program. It can render the first object fine but when the second object is to be rendered the error pops up. I simply fixed it by looking up the location with `glGetUniformLocation`, however i still do not understand why this problem manifested itself in such a weird way. First of all, the exact same code works for the main shading program (vertex shader and calling code is exactly the same), and second of all i do not get how the program was able to run when i did not use the depth texture. Is the driver able to optimize away entire rendering passes when they are not used in subsequent passes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can access a depth map in the same way as any other texture.
But, while [`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) provides window coordinates, [`texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) requires floating point coordinates in range [0.0, 1.0].

If the size of the depth map and the size of the viewport are equal (that should be the case in your case), then either use [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml):

```
float test = texelFetch(depth_map, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0).r;
```

Or you have to divide by the size of the texture ([`textureSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureSize.xhtml)):

```
float test = texture(depth_map, gl_FragCoord.xy / textureSize(depth_map, 0)).r;
```

Note, If the size of the depth map is not equal the viewport size, then you have to provide the viewport size as a uniform variable:

```
uniform vec2 vp_size;

float test = texture(depth_map, gl_FragCoord.xy / vp_size).r;
```

See [GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language - 4.4.1.3 Fragment Shader Inputs, p. 65](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> 4.4.1.3 Fragment Shader Inputs
>
> By default, gl_FragCoord assumes a lower-left origin for window coordinates and assumes pixel centers are located at half-pixel coordinates.

Extension of the answer:

The first pass is a "depth only" pass. You do not attach any color plane to the  frame buffer, so you should not write to any color plane, in the fragment shader, too. You have to use an empty `main`:

```
void main( void )
{
}
```

Note, if you want to set the fragment depth explicite, then you have to write to [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml). By default the `z` component of [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) is assigned to [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml):

```
void main( void )
{
    gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

Further, if you set the value for a uniform varibale, you have to install the current program (`glUseProgram`) **before** you set the uniform varible (`glUniformMatrix4fv`), because `glUniform*`specify the value of a uniform variable for the **current** program object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I dont know how i never heard of `texelFetch`. It does however not solve the problem at hand. I know that my code is erroneous and does not neccesarily do what i want, but i should still be able to execute it. Using `texelFetch` the bahviour is exactly the same - if i try to use `test` later in my shader, the program exits with code 1282, if i simply delete the multiplication in the fragment shader (i.e. `outColor =  lambert * texture(texture_main, uv);` everything works perfectly fine. My guess is that im not binding correctly, does that code seem okay?

Comment: Oh I see, this is how it works, makes sense. So in this case, without any outputs of the fragment shader, only the depth attachment gets written to? Makes sense i guess. Does not help the problem though; Sampling `depth_map` and using the result (so it does not get optimized away) still results in error code 1282. I really do appreciate the help though, thank you.

Comment: I indeed did, there seem to be no problems with that.

Comment: @MartinZach Do you `glUseProgram` **before** `glUniformMatrix4fv`? See the extension of the answer.

Comment: I did, yes. But appearently there still was a problem with that. I edited my main post. Everything seems to work now. Thank you for your help!